# Custom OCI website: Submitting FORM using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, abap

I've created a simple HTML website to consume an Odata service.

Basically, System A calls website and loads data from system B. When user clicks on button, submit data back to system A. This is for my OCI catalog functionality in IW32.

I dont know what the HOOK URL should be or how to post the data back to System A.

Am I missing anything?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="Component.js"></script>

<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Data from BPS</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Materials from BPS</p>

        Material:<input type="text" name="iMat" id="iMat"><br><br>
        Material Type:<input type="text" name="iMatType" id="iMatType"><br><br>
        Material Description:<input type="text" name="iMatDesc"  id="iMatDesc"><br><br>
<!--         <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" name="storeSAP" value="Transfer to SAP"/> -->

<form id="form" name="frmbasket" action="http://example.com?sap-client=800?&HOOK_URL=SAPEVENT:POST"
            method="post" target="_top">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit">
    <table id=table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Material</th>
                <th>MaterialType</th>
                <th>MaterialDesc</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-DESCRIPTION[1]" id="iMatDesc"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATNR[1]" id="iMat"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MATGROUP[1]" value = ""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-QUANTITY[1]" value = "1"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-UNIT[1]" value = "EA"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-PRICE[1]" value = "71.85">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-PRICEUNIT[1]" value = "5"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CURRENCY[1]" value = "USD">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LEADTIME[1]" value = "1"> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDOR[1]" value = ""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-VENDORMAT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTCODE[1]" value = ""> 
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-MANUFACTMAT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CONTRACT_ITEM[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-SERVICE[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ID[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_QUOTE_ITEM[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-EXT_PRODUCT_ID[1]" value = "">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-LONGTEXT_1:132[1]" value = "longtext_1: Test Text">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD1[1]" value = "custf 1.1">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD2[1]" value = "custf 1.2">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD3[1]" value = "custf 1.3">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD4[1]" value = "custf 1.4">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-CUST_FIELD5[1]" value = "custf 1.5">
            <input type="hidden" name="NEW_ITEM-SORTF[1]" id="iMat"> 

            </td>
        </tr>       
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>   
</body>
</html>
```

This is the Component.js which I've code the scripts for it

```
$(document)
        .ready(
                function() {
                    var query = "example.com" // root
                    // uri
                            + "?$format=json"; // give me json
                    // + "&$callback=callback"; //this is my callback

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType : 'json',
                        url : query,
                        // jsonpCallback : 'callback',
                         username: sUsername,
                         password: sPassword,
                         contentType: "application/json",
                         success : callback,
                         error: function (xhr) { //Add these parameters to display the required response
                             alert(xhr.status);
                             alert(xhr.statusText);
                         },
                    });
                    function callback(result) {
                        var html = '';
                        // var shows = result.d;
                        // $('#dsListTemplate').tmpl(shows).appendTo('#ds_shows');
                        $.each(result.d.results, function(i, post) {
                            html += '<tr>';
                            html += '<td>' + post.Material + '</td>';
                            html += '<td>' + post.MaterialType + '</td>';
                            html += '<td>' + post.MaterialDesc + '</td>';
                            html += '</tr>';
                            $('table tbody').html(html);
                        });
                    }
                });


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#table").on("click", "tr", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('#table tr').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');   


                 document.getElementById("iMat").value = this.cells[0].innerHTML;
                 document.getElementById("iMatType").value = this.cells[1].innerHTML;
                 document.getElementById("iMatDesc").value = this.cells[2].innerHTML;

/*        event = event || window.event; //for IE8 backward compatibility
        var target = event.target || event.srcElement; //for IE8 backward compatibility
        while (target && target.nodeName != 'tr') {
            target = target.parentElement;
        }
        //var cells = target.cells; //cells collection
        var cells = target.getElementsByTagName('td'); //alternative
        if (!cells.length || target.parentNode.nodeName == 'THEAD') { // if clicked row is within thead
            return;
        }
        var f1 = document.getElementById('Material');
        var f2 = document.getElementById('MaterialType');
        var f3 = document.getElementById('MaterialDesc');
        f1.value = cells[0].innerHTML;
        f2.value = cells[1].innerHTML;
        f3.value = cells[2].innerHTML;  */  
    });

});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#button" ).click(function() {
        $( "#form" ).submit();
    });
});


/*$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function() {

        var a=$("#form").serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://example.com:8000/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/XXXXXX/index.html?sap-client=800?&HOOK_URL=SAPEVENT:POST",
                    data: a, 
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert(data); 
                    }
                });     
            });
});
*/
```

So when the clicks Submit button, I'm supposed to transfer those NEW-FIELDS back to SAP system at IW32(Component tab)

Any advice?

Answer (score -1):

This is solved. Issue was due to the location where I coded the hidden input as well as action parameter

Comment: Thank you for self-answering this question 3.5 years ago instead of just forgetting about it like many other people do. But unfortunately this answer isn't very helpful for other users who encounter the same problem, because it doesn't contain any information about what *exactly* the mistake was and how *exactly* you fixed it.